# White space below footer on my bootstrap pages II

Tags: footer, space

I read the suggestions here: [White space below footer on my bootstrap pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28504270/white-space-below-footer-on-my-bootstrap-pages)

When I try this (position: absolute), it fixes the issue, but the lower parts of my website are no longer readable from small screens, because the footer is always overlapping parts of the website's body.

Is there a method to fix the footer as suggested, but still keep the complete body content readable from any screen size?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your page set up this simple fix may suffice...

```
 footer {
    margin-bottom: -20px;
}
```

N.B. I'm working with Bootstrap 4.